# How to auto indent code when opening the file in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is possible in the setting or via a plugin the make a file (html, css or php) automatically add whitespace (auto-indentation) on opening? I know that I can alter the setting to automatically remove whitespace on save, but I think I will loss the visual when editing.

I saw @rioV8 was not clear where I want the whitespace be added. So basically before each line of code (just like when auto-indent when hit enter). But apply to a single line of code.
example:

```
<html><head>some code</head><body><div></div><div><div><div></div></div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></body></html>
```

being converted to this when the file opens:

```
<html>
  <head>some code</head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

NB: I’m using the latest stable build of VS code.

Comment: A not very relevant sub-question: the reason to remove the whitespace (preferably on close instead of on save) was I read some post saying that it would provide faster load/response time for client, but for a simple php page (like a blog with no/limited js but a video player), how many faster would it be? Does it really make sense to remove those whitespace?

Comment: EDIT your question, where do you want that whitespace added

Comment: @rioV8 in front of each line of code